# How to take a picture using the default webcam in C#?

Tags: c#, video, webcam, photos

I need help to make my program. I have developed a form in C# that only has a textbox and a button to take a photo using the webcam and save it in the file path specified.

So I need a method to **start the webcam, take a photo and save it in the file path and close the webcam immediately**. No need to see what the webcam shows, just take the photo very fast and save it.

[image]

Any idea how I can do that? All comments are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is sadly **too broad**.  [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows APIs to access a webcam are native, but you can use well known wrappers:

First, [DirectShow.NET](https://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/)'s DxSnap sample

> Use DirectShow to take snapshots from the Still pin of a capture 
>   device.  Note the MS encourages you to use WIA for this, but if 
>   you want to do in with DirectShow and C#, here's how.

Related on StackOverflow:

- [Photo and video with webcam using DirectShowLib-2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668693/photo-and-video-with-webcam-using-directshowlib-2005)
- [Capturing frames from webcam using DirectShow.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750879/capturing-frames-from-webcam-using-directshow-net)
- [DirectShowLib - Can't take more than one picture with webcam. Got "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112830/directshowlib-cant-take-more-than-one-picture-with-webcam-got-insufficient)
- [DirectShow Library-How to capture image using directshow library without showing the webcam live images on the PictureBox or Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295667/directshow-library-how-to-capture-image-using-directshow-library-without-showing)
- [Capturing a photo on x86 Atom Windows 8, DirectShow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089469/capturing-a-photo-on-x86-atom-windows-8-directshow)

Second, Media Foundation.NET which wraps Media Foundation API

- See [How to grab constant stream of bitmap images from webcam in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357607/how-to-grab-constant-stream-of-bitmap-images-from-webcam-in-c-sharp) for related references

Then, other libraries, that eventually wrap mentioned above APIs (including referenced by links above)

Comment: Great, I'll try it. I've been researching on AForge.NET and seems a good solution too.